# Infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N} \times Y$ have a limit point.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. If $X$ has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property then $X$ is compact.

**Counterexample**

Let $Y$ consist of two points; give $Y$ the topology consisting of $Y$ and the empty set. Then the space $X = \mathbb{Z}_{+} \times Y$ is limit point compact, for every nonempty subset of $X$ has a limit point. It is not compact, for the covering of $X$ by the open set $U_n = \{n\} \times Y$ has not finite collection covering $X.$

---

My question is how to prove formally that each infinite subset of $X = \mathbb{Z}_{+} \times Y$ has a limit point?

I can see it but I don't know if that's enough for a formal justification:

$U_1=1\times Y=\{(1,y_1),(1,y_2):y_1,y_2\in Y\},U_2= \dots $

Thus $(1,y_1)\in U_1$ is a limit point of $U_1$ because each open set that contains $(1,y_1)$ also contains $(1,y_2)$. Similar with the others $U_i$.

Comment: Let $Y=\{0,1\}.$ If $p=(n,x)\in S\subset \Bbb Z^+\times Y$ then $q=(n,1-x)$ is a limit point of $S$ because any nbhd $U$ of $q$ contains a member ($p$) of  $S\cap (U$ \ $\{q\})$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Is $(n,x)$ an infinite subset?

Comment: No. $(n,x)$ is some (any) member of  $S$ and $S\subset  X$. The point is that $any$ non-empty $S\subset  X$ has a limit point.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet where the indiscrete topology was used (in the counterexample)?

Comment: If $U$ is a nbhd of $q=(n,1-x)$   then $q\in  A\times B\subset U$ where $A$ is open in $\Bbb Z^+$ and $B$ is open in $Y.$ And since $B\ne \phi$ we have $B=Y =\{0,1\}=\{x,1-x\}$  because $Y$ is anti-discrete.  And since $n\in A $ we have $p=(n,x)\in  \{(n,x),(n,1-x)\}=$ $  \{n\}\times Y=$ $\{n\} \times B$ $\subset A\times B$ $\subset U$. So $p\ne q \in U. $

Comment: In other words $q\in \overline {\{p\}}.$.... In any Tychonoff product topology $P=\prod_{j\in J}S_j $ of a family $ \{S_j\} _{j\in J}$ of spaces, if $T_j\subset S_j$ for each $ j,$ then  $Cl_P(\prod_{j\in J}T_j )  \supset \prod_{j\in J}Cl_{S_j}(T_j).$ .. In particular $Cl_{\Bbb Z^+\times Y}(\{n\}\times \{x\})\supset $ $\supset Cl_{\Bbb Z^+}\{n\}\times Cl_Y(\{x\})=$ $\{n\} \times Cl_Y(\{x\})=$ $\{n\}\times Y$ because $Y$ is anti-discrete.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually true (as it says in the text of the counterexample) that every nonempty subset has a limit point, regardless if it's infinite. Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb Z_+\times Y$ and let $(n,y)\in S.$ Then $(n,\bar y)$ is a limit point of $S,$ where $\bar y$ is the other element of $Y.$ The neighborhoods of $(n,\bar y)$ are sets of the form $A\times Y$ where $n\in A$ and thus $(n,y)$ is an element of $S$ that is in every neighborhood of $(n,\bar y)$.

Comment: where the indiscrete topology was used (in the counterexample)?